# Proportion of people supporting increase in cigarette taxes

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A recent study conducted by the government attempts to determine proportion of people who support further increase in cigarette taxes. In this study, **2500** voting age citizens were sampled, and it was found that **1900** of them were in favor of an increase in cigarette taxes. At level **α = 0.05**, do you believe that **78%** of all citizens are in favor of an increase in cigarette taxes.

(A) State the null and alternative hypotheses and compute the p-value.

(B) What is the smallest α you need to reject the null hypothesis.

My work:

(A) **H0: μ = 0.78** and **Ha: μ < 0.78**. I then found the test statistic at level **α = 0.05**:

**Z = (0.76-0.78)/[sqrt(0.78x0.22)/2500] = -2.4096 = -2.41**.

I then found the p-value: **P(z<-2.41) = 0.0080**.

(B) I found **Zα=Z0.05= 1.65** for the critical value, but I'm confused as to how to find the smallest **α** needed to reject the null hypothesis.

Any help is very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

When do you reject $H_0$? You reject it when your p-value is less than the stipulated $\alpha$-level. So the computed p-value is precisely the smallest $\alpha$-level that would been needed, because any higher $\alpha$-level would lead to a rejection, and any lower $\alpha$-level would lead you to fail to reject, as then the p-value would have been higher.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, would that simply mean that any p-value that is less than 0.05 would result in rejection?